# FPDF Multicell Function in one line parallel text

Tags: php, html, fpdf

[This is the Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wRFs.png) How can I use `multicell` and keep all the data in the same row? The data after the `multicell` is the following

```
$pdf->Cell(19   ,5,$billing['sn'],'L,R',0,'C');
$pdf->MultiCell(75  ,5,$billing['description'],'L,R',0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20   ,5,$billing['qty'],'L,R',0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(26   ,5,$billing['price'],'L,R',0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(50   ,5,$billing['item_total'],'L,R',1,'C');//end of line
```

Comment: What do you mean by "same row"? Can you provide a sketch of what it should look like?

Comment: The script [Table with MultiCells](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=3) can help.

Comment: I just updated my question. Please see the output above.